# Customize bibtex

Tags: bibtex, natbib

My Minimal Working Example is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{APA}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true}
\begin{document}
    Here initial concepts\citep{allen} and conditions are explained and
    several hypothesis\citep{bruner} are mentioned in brief.
        \citep{cox} did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{cox}  the definitive model is seen.
        \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

And the Bibliography file `mybib.bib` is

```
@mastersthesis{struss,
     AUTHOR = "Joseph A. Struss",
     TITLE = "An investigation of the sequence of utilizing a simulation in an introductory programming course",
     SCHOOL = "Iowa State University",
     YEAR = 1996}
@book{bruner,
     AUTHOR = "J. Bruner",
     Title = "The process of education",
     PUBLISHER = {Random House},
     ADDRESS = {New York},
     YEAR = 1960}
@article{allen,
  author =       "B. S. Allen",
  title =        "System-assigned learning strategies and CBI",
  journal =      "Journal of Instructional Computing Research",
  year =         1984,
  volume =       1,
  number =       1,
  pages =        "3--18"}
@Article{cox,
  author =       "S.~R. Cox",
  title =        "Computer-assisted instruction and student performance in macroeconomic principles", 
  journal =      "The Journal of Economic Education",
  year =         1974,
  volume =       6,
  number=        1,
  pages =        "29--37"}
```

For this , I got the output

[image]

Will I get the output like below

[image]

Comment: What is your explicit question?

Comment: Just to summarize in words: you want the bibliography to be essentially a numbered list with the author in bold?

Comment: @Torbjn T : Yes,  Number and author in bold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`natbib` was not designed for such things. So you need to change either `apa.bst` to add a font switch before the year or you need an ugly hack to switch the font automatically at the `(` before the year. Here the ugly hack:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{struss,
     AUTHOR = "Joseph A. Struss",
     TITLE = "An investigation of the sequence of utilizing a simulation in an introductory programming course",
     SCHOOL = "Iowa State University",
     YEAR = 1996}
@book{bruner,
     AUTHOR = "J. Bruner",
     Title = "The process of education",
     PUBLISHER = {Random House},
     ADDRESS = {New York},
     YEAR = 1960}
@article{allen,
  author =       "B. S. Allen",
  title =        "System-assigned learning strategies and CBI",
  journal =      "Journal of Instructional Computing Research",
  year =         1984,
  volume =       1,
  number =       1,
  pages =        "3--18"}
@Article{cox,
  author =       "S.~R. Cox",
  title =        "Computer-assisted instruction and student performance in macroeconomic principles", 
  journal =      "The Journal of Economic Education",
  year =         1974,
  volume =       6,
  number=        1,
  pages =        "29--37"}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@lbibitem}{\bfseries \the\c@NAT@ctr.\year@hack}{}{}
\begingroup
  \global\let\@bracket(
  \catcode`\(=\active
  \gdef\year@hack{%
    \catcode`\(=\active
    \def({\mdseries\@makeother\(\@bracket}%
  }
\endgroup
\makeatother
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    Here initial concepts \citep{allen} and conditions are explained and
    several hypothesis \citep{bruner} are mentioned in brief.
        \citep{cox} did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{cox}  the definitive model is seen.
        \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the ugly hack]

Without the ugly hack you need to make a copy of `apa.bst`, e.g., as `myapa.bst` in the document directory, open the file and replace:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { "\formatauthor{" * author format.names * "}" }
  if$
}
```

Then change the `\bibliographystyle` in your document and add the definition of `\formatauthor`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{struss,
     AUTHOR = "Joseph A. Struss",
     TITLE = "An investigation of the sequence of utilizing a simulation in an introductory programming course",
     SCHOOL = "Iowa State University",
     YEAR = 1996}
@book{bruner,
     AUTHOR = "J. Bruner",
     Title = "The process of education",
     PUBLISHER = {Random House},
     ADDRESS = {New York},
     YEAR = 1960}
@article{allen,
  author =       "B. S. Allen",
  title =        "System-assigned learning strategies and CBI",
  journal =      "Journal of Instructional Computing Research",
  year =         1984,
  volume =       1,
  number =       1,
  pages =        "3--18"}
@Article{cox,
  author =       "S.~R. Cox",
  title =        "Computer-assisted instruction and student performance in macroeconomic principles", 
  journal =      "The Journal of Economic Education",
  year =         1974,
  volume =       6,
  number=        1,
  pages =        "29--37"}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myapa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true}
\newcommand*{\formatauthor}[1]{%
  \textbf{\arabic{NAT@ctr}. #1}%
}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    Here initial concepts \citep{allen} and conditions are explained and
    several hypothesis \citep{bruner} are mentioned in brief.
        \citep{cox} did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{cox}  the definitive model is seen.
        \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and `biber`. `biblatex` was made to make things easier, i.e., to make it possible to change the formatting of the bibliography without bst-hacking.

Comment: I got the output but citations are not showing hyperlinked in my thesis

Comment: @RenjthVRavi: With exactly my examples? I have hyperlinks.